# Celery / Django Single Tasks being run multiple times

Tags: python, django

I'm facing an issue where I'm placing a task into the queue and it is being run multiple times.
From the celery logs I can see that the same worker is running the task ...

```
[2014-06-06 15:12:20,731: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: input.tasks.add_queue
[2014-06-06 15:12:20,750: INFO/Worker-2] starting runner..
[2014-06-06 15:12:20,759: INFO/Worker-2] collection started
[2014-06-06 15:13:32,828: INFO/Worker-2] collection complete
[2014-06-06 15:13:32,836: INFO/Worker-2] generation of steps complete
[2014-06-06 15:13:32,836: INFO/Worker-2] update created
[2014-06-06 15:13:33,655: INFO/Worker-2] email sent
[2014-06-06 15:13:33,656: INFO/Worker-2] update created
[2014-06-06 15:13:34,420: INFO/Worker-2] email sent
[2014-06-06 15:13:34,421: INFO/Worker-2] FINISH - Success
```

However when I view the actual logs of the application it is showing 5-6 log lines for each step (??).

Im using Django 1.6 with RabbitMQ. The method for placing into the queue is via placing a delay on a function.

This function (task decorator is added( then calls a class which is run.

Has anyone any idea on the best way to troubleshoot this ?

***Edit*** : As requested heres the code,

**views.py**

In my view im sending my data to the queue via ...

```
from input.tasks import add_queue_project

add_queue_project.delay(data)
```

**tasks.py**

```
from celery.decorators import task

@task()
def add_queue_project(data):
    """ run project """
    logger = logging_setup(app="project")

    logger.info("starting project runner..")
    f = project_runner(data)
    f.main()

class project_runner():
    """ main project runner """

    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.logger = logging_setup(app="project")

    def self.main(self):
        .... Code
```

**settings.py**

```
THIRD_PARTY_APPS = (
    'south',  # Database migration helpers:
    'crispy_forms',  # Form layouts
    'rest_framework',
    'djcelery',
)

import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()

BROKER_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
BROKER_PORT = 5672 # default RabbitMQ listening port
BROKER_USER = "test"
BROKER_PASSWORD = "test"
BROKER_VHOST = "test"
CELERY_BACKEND = "amqp" # telling Celery to report the results back to RabbitMQ
CELERY_RESULT_DBURI = ""

CELERY_IMPORTS = ("input.tasks", )
```

**celeryd**

The line im running is to start celery,

```
python2.7 manage.py celeryd -l info
```

Thanks,

Comment: These are not jobs created by celerybeat, correct?

Comment: Are you creating a task in some django signal handler? If yes then make sure that signal is not invoked multiple times.

Comment: please post your code

Comment: Ive added the code as requested.

Comment: Where is project_runner.main()?

Comment: I've added this I left this off for briefness. Project_runner.main has a bunch of code that runs other items. Nothing in there uses anything celery related.

Comment: what does logging_setup do? probably just logging_setup adding handler multiple times.

Comment: `def self.main(self):` should probably be `def main(self):` :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an exact answer for you, but there are a few things you should look into:

- `djcelery` is deprecated, so if you are using new version of `celery` there may be some sort of conflict.
- If your `input` app is listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` celery will discover it, so you don't need to add it to `CELERY_IMPORTS = ("input.tasks", )`, which maybe the cause of your problem, since tasks could be loaded multiple times
- try giving your task a name `@task(name='input.tasks.add')`, it will know that it is the same task, no matter how you import it.

Looking at your setting it looks like you are using an old version of celery, or you are using you old configuration for new version of celery. In any case make sure you have newest version and try this configuration instead of what you have:

```
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://<user>:<password>@localhost:5672/<vhost>'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

Now, you also will have to configure celery differently:

Get rid of `djcelery` stuff completely.

Create `proj/celery.py` inside your django project:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os

from celery import Celery

from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')

app = Celery('proj')

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

In your `proj/__init__.py`:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from proj.celery import app as celery_app
```

Then if your `input` app is a reusable app and is not part of your project use `@shared_task` instead of `@task` decorator.

Then run celery:

```
celery -A proj worker -l info
```

Hope it helps.